# How to kill PHP session

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to kill session after 30 seconds (testing) but it just doesn't
work. I don't understand why. I've followed relevant topic here on SO and tried to implement suggested solutions but it didn't work so please don't give me crap about duplicates.

this is my code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$userID = $row['userID'];
$_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

and in session.php I've got:

```
   if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) && (time() - $_SESSION['timeout']) > 30) {
        header("Location: loggedoutDisplay.php");
        exit();
    }
    $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

Providing more code:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($link,$query)) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $userID = $row['userID'];
                    $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
                    $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
                    header("Location: updatePage.php");
                }
            }
```

Here I'm starting session after user being successfully identified and redirected to `updatePage.php` where I need to session to end after 30 seconds.

Comment: "please don't give me crap about duplicates". Please don't be rude to people trying to help you.

Comment: anyway, what does "doesn't work" mean exactly? Does it go to loggedoutdisplay.php ever? what happens when you go to loggedoutdisplay.php? There's no code in this example which would end the session or remove any data from it. somewhere, in the relevant place, you need to be calling session_destroy().

Comment: Well ... it doesn't go to loggedoutDisplay.php at all. It's as if being ignored.

Comment: so, verify the values given by time() and $_SESSION['timeout'] in the case when you think it should be working. Are they what you expected?

Comment: Is there anything else I need to check ?

Comment: By "verify the values given by time() and $_SESSION['timeout']" you mean print it out and see what the output is. Correct ?

Comment: yes that's right. you can just use the echo statement. or if you've got an IDE that supports live debugging you can set breakpoints and examine them.

Comment: There is a good explanation in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/1643261

Comment: @sboye the code sample in there is pretty much identical to what OP has got, apart from the amount of time. So what's your point?

Comment: @ADyson I don't know what content is in loggedoutDisplay.php file

Comment: @ADyson   Looks like I've got values from those session variables wrong. The output is identical for both and it's 1506076583 which appears to me more like number of seconds from the beginning of unix time. I thought time() gives you, well, current time.

Comment: @sboye neither do I, but I fail to see how the link you posted is relevant to that fact. OP is already using the code in the style suggested there in the example code shown above, and is stating that loggedoutDisplay.php is not being visited, so the problem is happening before that.

Comment: @MarkyMark It seems you execute `$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();` in all executions. So your session will never expire

Comment: @MarkyMark does `session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$userID = $row['userID'];
$_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();` run before your `if` statement? If it does, then yes sboye is right and you always reset the timeout before you test it. The part `$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$userID = $row['userID'];
$_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();` should only run when the user first logs in, not for subsequent requests, until they log in again.

Comment: loggedoutDisplay.php contains only `session_unset();` and `session.destroy();` and html that informs user about being successfully logged out.

Comment: @MarkyMark When do you call session.php ?

Comment: `session.php` is being included on the top of each page.

Comment: @sboye  "MarkyMark It seems you execute $_SESSION['timeout'] = time(); in all executions. So your session will never expire"   I'll take it off and will see.

Answer (score 0):

see the documentation **session_destroy**
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you calling `session_destroy();` anywhere:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: `session_destroy();` is called when `loggedoutDisplay.php` is loaded. Sorry I should've mentioned that.

Comment: @MarkyMark it would be safer to call session_destroy() before you redirect to that page, in case the redirect fails or is not honoured by the client (setting that header is merely an instruction to the client to visit that page next, not an absolute command, you can't guarantee it will be carried out). Then you're certain that the session is dead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `session_destroy()` for `destroy` your current `session`

Answer (score 0):

`session_unset()` unsets `$_SESSION` variable for the run-time.

`session_destroy()` destroys session data in storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
 session_start();

 $timeout = 30; // Number of seconds until it times out.

 if(isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {

 // Get the difference between current time and the time the session was created
 $duration = time() - (int)$_SESSION['timeout'];

 if($duration > $timeout) { // If the difference is greater than 30s

 // Destroy the session
 session_unset();
 session_destroy();

 header("Location: loggedoutDisplay.php");
 exit();    

     }

}
```

Comment: I'll give it a go ...  :)

Comment: Nope. Didn't do a thing. This is making my head in. Such a simple concept these sessions but make it work drives me up to the wall.